# open the docbar left side menu in the custom jsp page in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, yui, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have a requirement that I need to add one link or button in docbar. From my custom jsp of the portlet when I click a link or button It should open the docbar left menu.For example in the docbar if I click on edit page it will open the left menu as shown below.How to achieve this ?

[image]

I have tried open the left menu link form my custom jsp page, it is not opened even I have included the docabr.js in custom jsp page. can any one guide me how to achieve this?
the following is my code which I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/liferay/dockbar.js"></script>

<portlet:renderURL var="editLayoutURL" windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>">
                <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/dockbar/edit_layout_panel" />
                <portlet:param name="closeRedirect" value="<%= PortalUtil.getLayoutURL(layout, themeDisplay) %>" />
                <portlet:param name="groupId" value="<%= String.valueOf(scopeGroupId) %>" />
                <portlet:param name="selPlid" value="<%= String.valueOf(plid) %>" />
            </portlet:renderURL>

<aui:nav-item anchorId="editLayoutPanel" cssClass="page-edit-controls" data-panelURL="<%= editLayoutURL %>" href="javascript:;" iconCssClass="icon-edit" label="edit" />
<aui:script position="inline" use="liferay-dockbar">
    Liferay.Dockbar.init('#<portlet:namespace />dockbar');

    var customizableColumns = A.all('.portlet-column-content.customizable');

    if (customizableColumns.size() > 0) {
        customizableColumns.get('parentNode').addClass('customizable');
    }
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to register your panel in the Dockbar like this:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-dockbar">
    Liferay.Dockbar.DOCKBAR_PANELS.myPanel = {
        css: 'lfr-has-mypanel',
        id: 'myPanel',
        node: null,
        showFn: A.bind(Liferay.Dockbar._showPanel, Liferay.Dockbar),
        tpl: '<div class="lfr-add-panel lfr-admin-panel" id="{0}" />'
    };
</aui:script>
```

You can check out a working implementation of this in the [Audience Targetting Simulator Hook](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-apps-content-targeting/tree/master/simulator-hook)